# Programmatically clicking a link in android browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to click on dynamically created click-to-call link in Android browser, but nothing happen.

Create element:

```
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = "tel:+1-303-499-7111";
```

then event and fire click:

```
  var evt = new MouseEvent("click");
  link.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

or even

```
  link.click();
```

It works fine on chrome's mobile mode and iOS device, but doesn't work in android browser.
However if create element in HTML `<a href="tel:+1-303-499-7111">+1 (303) 499-7111</a>` and click manually, everything is working

Comment: It's likely Android does not support it. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: Yeah. Seems like there is no way to do this. Anyway, thank you @evolutionxbox